# Log4J2 SizeBasedT​riggeringP​olicy not working properly

Tags: log4j2

I use the latest build log4j2 beta9, it seem the RollingRandomAccessFile and RollingRandomAccessFile not working properly

Yes, it create archive after reach the specific file size limit but after that, log file's size keep increase (i.e not roll over) and that is only one achieve create even I had set the max to 3.

Here my appender setting for log4j2.xml.  Any help?

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="d:/logs/mylog.log"
 filePattern="d:/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/idmIntg-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 KB"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug. Can you raise this issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 ?
Please include your log4j2.xml and any other details that may be relevant (OS, java version).

Answer (score 0):

Configuration does not work properly on tomcat-6.For 20 MB log file, after tomcat server restart on first run, it works fine and archive files but on other turns, it does not archive log file even it is bigger than 20MB.

if you configure as 10 KB, it works fine.

I just report [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1170) to the Log4j team.